# Android app does not get updated using Android Studio (2.1.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

When I hit run, Android Studio installs the app on my device (not emulator), but sometimes the code does not change (e.g. some Logs still output to the console whilw they actually got removed).

I faced a similar problem before: When I tried to install the app, Android Studio said there were no changes made, so it canceled the process. I could solve this problem by unchecking "Skip installation if APK has not changed" in "Installation Options". (I disabled "Instant Run" as well).

Since Android Studio now returns "Success" when I run the app, I thought the problem was my device, so I restarted it, but nothing changed. Then I cleaned the caches of Android Studio, restarted AS, installed the app and it worked...

Because I don't want to clean my cache and restart Android Studio every hour, I look for a solution on this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have Instant Run enabled? I suggest you to disable it because at this date it's still very buggy,

Comment: Yes, already disabled it, sry I forget to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

This happens occasionally for me, and the best solution I've found is uninstalling the app from my phone and reinstalling it. To uninstall the app, hold down on the icon in the app list menu and drag it to the uninstall field. It should always reinstall with the updated code.

Comment: This solution might work, but the problem is that all the data of the app gets lost... A similar approach is to change the versionCode, which also worked for me, but I don't want to change something everytime I update my app.

Comment: I agree it's definitely not a perfect solution. You will lose any persistent data local to the app, so if there is important data I wouldn't recommend it.